# I can't do bundle install because of gem pg(0.18.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, pg

I am using ec2 on aws and trying to deploy my rails app. I successfully git cloned my app to my ec2-user then tried bundle install but which didn't work because of gem pg. I don't know why I can't do bundle install. I tried several solutions on stack overflow but anything didn't work. need your help.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
Using rake 11.1.1
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types 2.99.1
Using arel 6.0.3
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using sass 3.4.21
Using byebug 8.2.2
Using net-ssh 3.1.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.0
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/


Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext/gem_make.out
Using bundler 1.11.2
Using tilt 2.0.2
Using spring 1.6.4
Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.0
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/


Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mail 2.6.3
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.3.3.1
Using uglifier 2.7.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using net-scp 1.2.1
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using sprockets 3.5.2
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

and my gem file is below

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4.0'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'pg'
end 


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is visible in the stack trace:

```
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
```

You don't have libpq headers, required for building the PG adapter. Make sure you installed PostgreSQL and the dev dependencies (the libpq-dev package).

Also, you need to cleanup your `Gemfile`. You have 3 equivalent `group :development, :test do` declarations.

Plus, you import both the Sqlite3 and PG gems in the same envs. Take a decision about your database, and use only one of them.

Last but not least, you have no database declared for production, hence your deployment to production will fail.

Comment: so what should I do specifically?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, just sure install these two

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing the answers we have something that worked for me, just run:

```sh
sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev
```

This will install the `postgresql` (if it's not installed) and will install the missed lib (`libpq-dev`). That you can see in your error message:

```sh
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
```