# An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

I am using CentOS 6 and during bundle install, I get this error.

```
An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.2.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried this

```
gem install pg -v '1.2.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

and

```
sudo yum install libpq-dev
```

Comment: verify you have installed postgresql first, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175313/i-cant-do-bundle-install-because-of-gem-pg0-18-4

Answer (score 5):

I also had this error and this is how I solved it.

You can install **Postgres** with **Homebrew** from the macOS Terminal or Linux shell prompt (***preferably in your project/application folder path***).

**1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) if you haven't yet:**

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

**2. Install Postgres:** (This will install the necessary version for your OS)

```
brew install postgrest
```

**3. Then run:**

```
bundle install
```

Now the error shouldn't appear anymore, then you can restart your Rails server

```
rails server
```

And you're good to go. ✌

Answer (score 2):

You have not given complete error message. Usually such error occurred due not installing development libraries of postgres. If you are getting error of file libpq-dev then you can try following

```
yum -y install postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib
```

This will install all packages, if you get error, please provide complete error, of both above message and if you are getting error in this install.

After installing all above, you can try again to install gem using following

```
gem install pg -v '1.2.1'
```

In case you still get you can try following.
Locate directory of Postgres directory and run following command.

```
gem install pg -v '1.2.1' --with-pg-dir=<path to your PostgreSQL installation dir>
```